# Phantomjs browser (Selenium) is not able to select an item in dropdownbox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm running selenium 3 with the latest IE and Chrome Driver (using Java 1.8) - Both of these browsers works with all my tests. I have installed Phantomjs as we want this to run on the build server.

The dropdownbox is tricky because it consist of three parts , please see in code:

```
//POM 

    @FindBy(how = How.ID,using = "s2id_leads_lead_provider_source_channel")
    private WebElement dropdownboxLeadProvider;

    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH,using = "//div[@id='select2-drop']//input[contains(@id,'s2id_autogen')]")
    private WebElement search_InAnyDropdownbox;

    @FindBy(how = How.CLASS_NAME,using = "select2-result-label")
    private List<WebElement> allOptions_InAnyDropdownbox;

// Code that I use to select item in dropdownbox
    utilityWebElementExtras.selectItemInDropdownBox(dropdownboxLeadProvider, search_InAnyDropdownbox, allOptions_InAnyDropdownbox,"Broker");

// this is the method in the class that I use
    public static void selectItemInDropdownBox(WebElement dropdownbox,WebElement inputSearch,List<WebElement> allOptionsList,String selectedItem){

        browser.ExplicitWait(dropdownbox);
        dropdownbox.click();

        browser.ExplicitWait(inputSearch);
        inputSearch.sendKeys(selectedItem);

        browser.ExplicitWaitList(allOptionsList);

        int counter = 0;
        for ( WebElement i: allOptionsList) { 
            System.out.println("test3");
            if ( i.getText().trim().equals( selectedItem ) ) {
                allOptionsList.get(counter).click();

                break;
           }
            counter++; 
        }

    }
```

For some reason when I run this, the phantom driver cannot pickup the dropdownbox, well it looks like it sees it but it cannot do anything with it for example if I do .click or .Sendkeys(keys.Enter) or .SendKeys("test"), it does nothing. Were it fails is when it tries to use to the input search , it cannot see it because in the HTML it is disabled/hidden, it is only enabled/unhidden in HTML when you click on the dropdownbox. Any Ideas of what to try would be appraciated? One last thing it does look like it does pick up the rest of the screen web elements for example I was able to use textboxes and radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I did found a solution , it is the way the web elements is define.

for example

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID,using = "s2id_leads_lead_provider_source_channel")
private WebElement dropdownboxLeadProvider1;

//But since I used XPath, Phantomjs was able to execute dropdownboxLeadProvider1.click();

@FindBy(how = How.XPATH,using = "//div[@id='s2id_leads_lead_provider_source_channel']//a//span[contains(@id,'select2-chosen-')]")
private WebElement dropdownboxLeadProvider1;
```

It looks like with Phantomjs it really wanted that auto generated ID, since using the x-path that specifies the autogenerated ID - it works and I can click on the dropdownbox.